# Chrony sync time ignoring maxpoll

Tags: time-synchronization, chrony

I have a Rocky Linux 9.2 server.  We monitor it via check_mk and regularly get a warning that last time since sync can exceed 1 hour.  Note how in the sources below the mansfield.id.au source is at 64 minutes.

From my limited understanding of ntp, the maxpoll of 10 specified below is equal to 1024 seconds?

```
server 0.au.pool.ntp.org iburst minpoll 6 maxpoll 10
server 1.au.pool.ntp.org iburst minpoll 6 maxpoll 10
server 2.au.pool.ntp.org iburst minpoll 6 maxpoll 10
server 3.au.pool.ntp.org iburst minpoll 6 maxpoll 10
```

Tracking - after chrony finally sync'd, that update interval changed to 4135.0 seconds.

```
[]#chronyc tracking
Reference ID    : 6EE87216 (mansfield.id.au)
Stratum         : 3
Ref time (UTC)  : Wed Jan 24 00:27:13 2024
System time     : 0.000012703 seconds slow of NTP time
Last offset     : -0.000079763 seconds
RMS offset      : 0.000147473 seconds
Frequency       : 10.848 ppm fast
Residual freq   : -0.001 ppm
Skew            : 0.052 ppm
Root delay      : 0.032765601 seconds
Root dispersion : 0.005266702 seconds
Update interval : 1036.2 seconds
Leap status     : Normal
```

Sources

```
[]# chronyc sources
MS Name/IP address         Stratum Poll Reach LastRx Last sample
===============================================================================
^- 192.9.171.167                 2  10   377   254   +511us[ +511us] +/-   63ms
^* mansfield.id.au               2  10   377   64m  -2117us[-2197us] +/-   19ms
^- ntp2.ds.network               2  10   377  1007    +16ms[  +16ms] +/-  173ms
^- 220-158-215-20.broadband>     2  10   377   943    +73us[  +73us] +/-   81ms
```

Does anyone know why it seems to ignore the maxpoll value, or is there some configuration that is missing/wrong?

thanks

jc

Answer (score 1):

That is healthy chrony output. Four sources, all reachable recently, precision in the below 1 ms range and delay in tens of milliseconds, and you are 3 hops (stratum) from the reference clock. Typical for internet NTP servers.

Your output there I would not consider actionable, and so not a thing to alert on. Its possible some temporary problem is no longer there after the alert fired, or the check is incorrectly alerting on things.

chrony's poll/minpoll/maxpoll configuration is log base 2, so typical values of 10 are 1024 seconds. Yes, it is normal for healthy chrony instances to ease up on the  packets and end up sending only a few an hour. Much longer maxpoll is possible, but approximately no one changes the default.

I'm not familiar with checkmk. Fortunately it appears to have an open source core with the crony plugin. I'm going off of [chrony.py tagged v2.2.0](https://github.com/Checkmk/checkmk/blob/v2.2.0/cmk/base/plugins/agent_based/chrony.py).  These are the keys it extracts from `chronyc tracking` output

```
Reference ID
System time
Stratum
Ref time (UTC)
```

Check uses the current time minus the parsed Ref time to make a threshold for "Time since last sync" with apparently default thresholds of 1800 and 3600 seconds. Seems error prone to have to parse a formatted time, but at least they use Python library functions.

I think this part of the alert is pointless and not actionable. Failing to synchronize will return the error stratum number 16, and the check already alerts on stratum > 10. The check also alerts if it cannot parse an IP address from Reference ID. And if even if chrony loses all inputs, it will keep disciplining the clock based on known drift.

Disable the delay part of this check. Or at least set it to much higher threshold, maybe 1 or 2 days. I don't care that the last NTP packet was 30 minutes ago, but 30 hours on an always-on server without an reference clock measurement might be interesting.

Also diversify your sources to include non internet ones. If you deal with hardware, you can get NTP appliances, likely from a satellite signal. Or there might be an NTP server on the local network already, in some clouds there is one as a part of a metadata service.